# Problem with Analytical Integration with Constant

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Could you help me out on how to integrate this long equation with constant as it is indefinite integral so I assumed I could not use numerical integration (eg: Simpsons's 3/8 Rule or Trapezoidal Rule) as it required a limit.

```
a1=-0.0317138 - 0.00395833 (-0.5 + r) (1.02817 + 
    3.98107/(5.36839*10^11/r - 1.*10^12 r)^(1/20) + 
    2./((1.27718 - 0.666667 r - 0.333333 r^2)/(1. + r))^(1/20) + 
    3./((3.05377 - 0.888889 r - 0.111111 r^2)/(4. + r))^(1/20) + 
    3.01772/(-((1. (-0.675531 + 0.125 r + r^2))/(0.0625 + r)))^(
    1/20) + 3.03794/(-((1. (-0.867019 + 0.285714 r + r^2))/(
      0.142857 + r)))^(1/20) + 
    2.04096/(-((1. (-1.14539 + 0.5 r + r^2))/(0.25 + r)))^(1/20) + 
    3.08948/(-((1. (-1.57936 + 0.8 r + r^2))/(0.4 + r)))^(1/20) + 
    3.12414/(-((1. (-2.32712 + 1.25 r + r^2))/(0.625 + r)))^(1/20) + 
    3.23431/(-((1. (-7.80849 + 3.5 r + r^2))/(1.75 + r)))^(1/20)) + 
    0.125 (-0.5 + r) (0.196614 +  1.32702*10^-12 (5.36839*10^11/r 
    - 1.*10^12 r)^(19/20) + 
    0.666667 ((1.27718 - 0.666667 r - 0.333333 r^2)/(1. + r))^(
     19/20) + ((3.05377 - 0.888889 r - 0.111111 r^2)/(4. + r))^(
    19/20) + 
    0.894139 (-((1. (-0.675531 + 0.125 r + r^2))/(0.0625 + r)))^(
     19/20) + 
    0.787613 (-((1. (-0.867019 + 0.285714 r + r^2))/(0.142857 + r)))^(
     19/20) + 
    0.453547 (-((1. (-1.14539 + 0.5 r + r^2))/(0.25 + r)))^(19/20) + 
    0.572125 (-((1. (-1.57936 + 0.8 r + r^2))/(0.4 + r)))^(19/20) + 
    0.462835 (-((1. (-2.32712 + 1.25 r + r^2))/(0.625 + r)))^(
     19/20) + 
    0.239579 (-((1. (-7.80849 + 3.5 r + r^2))/(1.75 + r)))^(19/20))

TRY = Integrate[(a1*r), r, GeneratedParameters -> S]
```

It seems mathematica still could not solve it as the OUTPUT (below) appears exactly the same like the question.

```
Integrate[
 r (-0.0317138 - 
    0.00395833 (-0.5 + r) (1.02817 + 
       3.98107/(5.36839*10^11/r - 1.*10^12 r)^(1/20) + 
       2./((1.27718 - 0.666667 r - 0.333333 r^2)/(1. + r))^(1/20) + 
       3./((3.05377 - 0.888889 r - 0.111111 r^2)/(4. + r))^(1/20) + 
       3.01772/(-((1. (-0.675531 + 0.125 r + r^2))/(0.0625 + r)))^(
       1/20) + 3.03794/(-((1. (-0.867019 + 0.285714 r + r^2))/(
         0.142857 + r)))^(1/20) + 
       2.04096/(-((1. (-1.14539 + 0.5 r + r^2))/(0.25 + r)))^(1/20) + 
       3.08948/(-((1. (-1.57936 + 0.8 r + r^2))/(0.4 + r)))^(1/20) + 
       3.12414/(-((1. (-2.32712 + 1.25 r + r^2))/(0.625 + r)))^(
       1/20) + 3.23431/(-((1. (-7.80849 + 3.5 r + r^2))/(1.75 + r)))^(
       1/20)) + 
    0.125 (-0.5 + r) (0.196614 + 
       1.32702*10^-12 (5.36839*10^11/r - 1.*10^12 r)^(19/20) + 
       0.666667 ((1.27718 - 0.666667 r - 0.333333 r^2)/(1. + r))^(
        19/20) + ((3.05377 - 0.888889 r - 0.111111 r^2)/(4. + r))^(
       19/20) + 
       0.894139 (-((1. (-0.675531 + 0.125 r + r^2))/(0.0625 + r)))^(
        19/20) + 
       0.787613 (-((1. (-0.867019 + 0.285714 r + r^2))/(
          0.142857 + r)))^(19/20) + 
       0.453547 (-((1. (-1.14539 + 0.5 r + r^2))/(0.25 + r)))^(
        19/20) + 
       0.572125 (-((1. (-1.57936 + 0.8 r + r^2))/(0.4 + r)))^(
        19/20) + 
       0.462835 (-((1. (-2.32712 + 1.25 r + r^2))/(0.625 + r)))^(
        19/20) + 
       0.239579 (-((1. (-7.80849 + 3.5 r + r^2))/(1.75 + r)))^(
        19/20))), r, GeneratedParameters -> S]
```

I don't know what is wrong with my coding. Anyone can help to sort this out ? Thank you.

Comment: Look at the result of `Rationalize[a1,10^-20]`.

Comment: I know Rationalize is used to convert a1 to rational number. I tried to do and it still appear the same like I showed above (the output).

Comment: I have strong doubts the binomials in `Rationalize[a1,10^-20]` can be integrated in a closed form (see [Математический анализ и геометрия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Чебышёв,_Пафнутий_Львович) in Russian). This is a problem, not `GeneratedParameters -> S`. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: `Integrate[r Rationalize[a1, 0], r]` on "12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" produces a result after about 15 minutes.  The `LeafCount` is `1854`, which is too large to reproduce here.  It involves several instances of `Hypergeometric2F1`, as well as simpler functions.

Comment: If you cannot obtain the solution using the code in my previous comment, provide your email address, and I shall send you a notebook with the solution.  Or, if memory is a problem, try breaking the integrand into pieces and integrate each separately.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: Can't reproduce it in 12.3 on Windows 10 Pro. The input is returned in 2700.25 s. The executed .nb file on demand through Dropbox.

Comment: @user64494  I just reproduced my calculation, starting with a fresh notebook and again copying the code from the question and performing the integral with `Integrate[r Rationalize[a1, 0], r]`.  Required about 12 minutes.

Comment: `Integrate[r Simplify@Rationalize[a1, 0], r]` is a little faster, producing a results in `382 sec` , according to `AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: Hi @bbgodfrey . I tried to solve using this Integrate[r Simplify@Rationalize [a1, 0], r] as u did. However, the output I got is exactly the same like the input.  Do you mind to share your notebook via email to me (aifazainul94@gmail.com). Thank u so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 6-processor, 16 GB PC and

```
$Version
(* 12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021) *)
```

I can perform the integral in about seven minutes (`AbsoluteTiming`).  The result is too large (`LeafCount` of `1854`) to reproduce here, so I provide only the integral of one of the `46` terms in the integrand.

```
Rationalize[Expand[a1][[29]], 0]
(* (1514341 (-((-(114539/100000) + r/2 + r^2)/(1/4 + r)))^(19/20))/
   (1499571496 (-(114539/100000) + r/2 + r^2)) *)

Integrate[r %, r]
(* (7571705 5^(1/4) (114539 - 50000 r - 100000 r^2)^(1/20) 
   (-21 Hypergeometric2F1[1/40, 1/20, 41/40, (6250 (1 + 4 r)^2)/120789] + (1 + 4 r) 
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/20, 21/40, 61/40, (6250 (1 + 4 r)^2)/120789]))/
   (15745500708 2^(17/20) 3^(1/10) 13421^(1/20) 
   ((114539 - 50000 r - 100000 r^2)/(1 + 4 r))^(1/20)) *)
```

Comment: thank you so much it was really helpful